# Extracting value in php

Tags: php, string

I have a string like this "firstname lastname(email)" and I want to extract "email" from this string in php. What should I do? any solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where

```
$str = "firstname lastname(email)";
```

try

```
$email = substr($str, stripos($str,"(")); // still has closing ) 
$email = substr($email, 0,strlen($email)-1); // removes )
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular expression and [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)?

e.g. matches anything in brackets:

```
preg_match ('/\((.+)\)/', $subject, $matches);
```

e.g. or parse for an email:

```
preg_match ('/^([\w\.-]{1,64}@[\w\.-]{1,252}\.\w{2,4})$/', $subject, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this function [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
preg_match_all("/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i", $string, $email);
```

The variable `$email[0]` holds the email extracted from the variable `$string`. If you have many such emails increment in index of the array variable `$email`.

Answer (score 0):

try code

```
 $str = "firstname lastname(email)"; //Given string 
 $begin =  strpos($str , "(") + 1;    //string position of first letter of email
 $length =  strpos($str , ")") - $begin; // Total length of email

 echo substr($str , $begin  , $length );  // using substr php function
```

thanks